# javascript html height vs window height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am creating some javascript that needs to determine the amount of space available above and below an input box and do some calculations/manipulations with that value. Basically I get $input.offset().height to get the amount above, and then substract this from the height of the window and the height of the input box to get the amount available below.

The problem is that I need to support IE Quirks mode for various reasons that can't be avoided. The window height is always null or 0 but if I query the html height, it seems to give me the correct window/viewport height.

**Code example**

```
$(window).height(); // This is 0
$("html").height(); // This is fairly accurate for the viewport height


var bottom_distance = $(window).height() - ($input.offset().top + $input.height);
var quirks_distance = $("html").height() - ($input.offset().top + $input.height); // Is this reliable?
```

My question is, can I use this value `$("html").height()` reliably?

Comment: if your want full page height use $(document).height()

Comment: Any chance describe what's your main goal is? it doesn't sounds a good solution design for rendering Web UI in this way at all. It can get very challenging working on multiple browsers, not to mention get it work on different mobile devices

Comment: Our application is only supported on IE. Basically I want a dropdown to open up or down depending on how much space is available on either side. I need to query the amount of space below and set the height of the dropdown to a value within that space (unless it is too small then open above)

Comment: I need the "viewport" height to base the distance above and below on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go mate:

**Edit**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var viewportwidth;
 var viewportheight;
 // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use
 // window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight
 if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
 {
      viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
      viewportheight = window.innerHeight
 }
// IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first
// line in the document)
 else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
     && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
     'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0)
 {
       viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
       viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
 }
 // older versions of IE
 else
 {
       viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
       viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
 }
document.write('<p>Your viewport width is '+viewportwidth+'x'+viewportheight+'</p>');
</script>
```

Got the code from this site:
http://andylangton.co.uk/blog/development/get-viewport-size-width-and-height-javascript

I tried this in 4 versions of IE (6, 8, 10, 11) and 3 different screens seems reliable

I hope it helps.

But doing this in IE 6 and below seems like a pain in the rear hopefully you are working with anything above IE 6

Comment: Answers that are just a link aren't very useful. What if this were to be accepted, and then someone finds this question later, and the link is now dead?

Comment: This is exactly the clarification I was looking for. Thank you for your detailed answer. And thankfully I don't have to worry about <ie6, we really support ie8+ but some legacy code is still in quirks mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).height();
```

Comment: This would give me the full height, I only need the "viewport" height.